# font awesome icons did not loaded on my site

Tags: css

I have an error on my site where all font awesome icons although I added font awesome. This is my site http://londonpostjournal.com/

[image]

```css
.login-top .lg-in::before {
    font-family: "Fontawesome";
    content: "f090";
    padding-right: .3em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: You haven't forgotten to include '<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look through the http://fontawesome.io/ css.

you content should headed with \

also they provide a lot of pre packed classes. you can take a look and use them. no need for define your class for most cases

your css should be

```
.login-top .lg-in::before {
    font-family: "Fontawesome";
    content: "\f090";
    padding-right: .3em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using FontAwesome's CSS `content` is that you need to **escape** it with a backslash:

```
content: "\f090";
```

Also note that you can simply use an icon with the class `fa-[ICON]`, where `[ICON]` is equivalent to the name of the icon you want to use (in this case, `sign-in`), thus avoiding the need to use any CSS at all:

```css
.css::before {
    font-family: "Fontawesome";
    content: "\f090";
    padding-right: .3em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Icon Usage
  <div class="css">CSS Usage</div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!